# Finding $\inf([\sqrt{2},2] \cap \mathbb{Q})$

Tags: real-analysis, definition, supremum-and-infimum

I came across the comments here:
[Prove that $\inf\left\{t>\sigma:X_t=\varepsilon\right\}$ is a stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2289657/154124)

and I'm curious about finding $\inf([\sqrt{2},2] \cap \mathbb{Q})$

Please, tell me if I'm wrong (I want to clarify my understanding of supremum and infimum): I think the problem here is in the definitions:

Let be the set:
$$U = \{x \in \mathbb{R}; x = inf([\sqrt{2},2] \cap \mathbb{Q}])\}$$
In this case, the comment given by Did is right, we have $U = \{\sqrt{2}\}$

But if I define:
$$U = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}; x = inf([\sqrt{2},2] \cap \mathbb{Q}])\}$$
Then 0xbadf00d is right: $U = \{\}$

Comment: What does this $U$ thing have anything to do with $\inf([\sqrt{2},2]\cap{\bf Q})$?

Comment: @Jack, I agree it's awkward notation, but it's the set containing just the element $\inf([\sqrt{2},2]\cap \mathbb Q$ if it exists, otherwise it's the empty set.

Comment: Infimum of a subset of the real numbers, if it exists, is **by definition** a real number. It may or may be in ${\bf Q}$.

Comment: Everything you say sounds correct.  When talking about infima and suprema of sets or subsets of real numbers we generally allow our infima and suprema to be real as well.  If you want to specify that our the numbers in our sets are living in a more restrictive universe that our infima and suprema must also be a part of, then they might not exist within that set.  That is part of the strength of including irrational numbers: any bounded set of real numbers will always have a supremum and infimum in the reals.  Whether or not that supremum is also a rational is not guaranteed.

Comment: The issue here is whether the inf is taken over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q.$ You're correct that it is $\sqrt{2}$ when taken over $\mathbb R$ and does not exist when taken over $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I wanted to define a set that contains the elemnt that happens to be the infimum, and check if this set is empty

Comment: @Broken_Window:  You can define your set at $\{\inf((\sqrt 2,2])\} \cap \Bbb Q$.  Now the $\inf$ is clearly $\sqrt 2$ and then you check whether it is rational.

Answer (score 0):

For Every, $x\in [\sqrt{2},2]\cap{\Bbb Q}$ we have, $x\ge \sqrt2$

and for a given $\epsilon>0$ since, $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ there exists

$x_\epsilon\in [\sqrt{2},\min(2,\sqrt2+\epsilon)]\cap{\Bbb Q}$  that is, $x_\epsilon\in [\sqrt{2},2]\cap{\Bbb Q}$ and $$\sqrt2 \le x_\epsilon \le \sqrt2+\epsilon$$
 this prove by definition that :$$\inf\{[\sqrt{2},2]\cap{\Bbb Q}\}=\sqrt{2}.$$